# Установка wordpress на OpenServer

Tags: php, wordpress, установка

Прослушал https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fESUgt6yfrE . После копирования содержимого папки wordpress (из архива) в папку mysite.ru и открытия адреса http://mysite.ru получаю в результате страницу https://keramzit.ru/. Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

Comment: См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562 Но лучше не юзать виндовые недофорки, а работать сразу на хостинге.

Answer (score 2):

DNS никто не отменял. С какого перепуга ты открывая ссылку по имени домена ожидаешь, что откроется нечто в локальной папке?

Ну а уж если такое поведение действительно надо, то надо настроить сайт на дефаултном порту (80) и в hosts прописать переопределение ip для доменного имени. Но вообще-то это ерунда.

Comment: Ещё было бы справедливо посоветовать ТС открыть http://localhost/ :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, логично. Что-то я не подумал, что это тоже надо написать. Интересно, что в видео открывают, а то мне было лень его смотреть...